# reading json file with table names in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm new to ag-grid, and am trying to enhance their demo found here.

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/#fetch-remote-data

Their raw github link allows you to fetch the data in their format, shown like this.

```
columnDefs = [
    { field: 'make' , sortable: true},
    { field: 'model' , sortable: true},
    { field: 'price', sortable: true }
];
```

and

```
  rowData = [
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
];
```

Now, the remote data would take on a different look with an OnInit method and so on, but just for the sake of argument, this is how it would work hard coded.

With the contents of the html file looking like:

```
<ag-grid-angular
style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"
class="ag-theme-alpine"
[rowData]="rowData"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

and the module having the following:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular'; /...

../
```

But what if the json file you're trying to read looks like the following? How do you account for that?

```
{ "cars" :
[
{ "make": "Toyota", "model": "Celica", "price": 35000 },
{ "make": "Ford", "model": "Mondeo", "price": 32000 },
{ "make": "Porsche", "model": "Boxter", "price": 72000 }
],
"trucks" : [
{ "make": "Chevy", "model": "Silverado", "price": 38000 },
{ "make": "Ford", "model": "F350", "price": 41000 },
{ "make": "Dodge", "model": "Ram", "price": 36500 }
 ]
}
```

I saw this earlier question here,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419109/angular-ag-grid-compressed-json , but I'm not sure if that's really addressing the same issue or not. I think I added all the needed and pertinent code here, but let me know if I've overlooked something that would be needed to help answer this.

I appreciate any guidance you guys here on SO can give me!

Comment: You mean you want something like [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/)?

Comment: well, that's grouping, and sometimes that can work, but in the above scenario the cars and trucks would be table names. I was thinking it would be something like cars.make, cars.model and cars.price, and then trucks.make, trucks.model and trucks.price ....but not so?